# React Native Empty Space at the top of the screen i don't know where it comes from

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-emulator, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86EVc.png)
That's one of my application screens. There is an empty space I couldn't understand where it comes from. I use Navigations, Draver, NativeStack, MaterialTopBars set to the bottom each navigators headerShown is false and also this empty space is on top of the headers.

I tried to change all options to see where it come from but I couldn't. And this is on all my screens

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Without any reproducible example it's basically impossible to help with your issue. Please see [ask] and how to make a [mcve].

Comment: Hey thats your SafeAreaView. Please read the documentation to makes changes to it. https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview

Comment: give me code so I can understand

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a  and an  in your App.tsx.
This View component is the one that is creating this space. :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).